# Memcache `delete_misses` are very high compared to `delete_hits` while `evictions` are 0

Tags: memcached

I am using Memcached for caching html for my project. But most of the pages cached are not extracted and result in server timeout. Also the `delete_misses` are at pretty higher end as compared to `delete_hits` while `evictions` are 0.

Here are memcached stats:

STAT pid 18323
STAT uptime 384753
STAT time 1468390067
STAT version 1.4.27
STAT libevent 1.4.13-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 75.178571
STAT rusage_system 31.052279
STAT curr_connections 10
STAT total_connections 9517
STAT connection_structures 25
STAT reserved_fds 20
STAT cmd_get 9410
STAT cmd_set 991
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 7788
STAT get_misses 1622
STAT get_expired 265
STAT delete_misses 18439
STAT delete_hits 117
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 45007488
STAT bytes_written 321441436
STAT limit_maxbytes 1073741824
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT hash_power_level 16
STAT hash_bytes 524288
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT log_worker_dropped 0
STAT log_worker_written 0
STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
STAT log_watcher_sent 0
STAT bytes 12134672
STAT curr_items 266
STAT total_items 991
STAT expired_unfetched 188
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 340
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 0
END

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that key are correct, that might happened because items were expired.